# MarkLogic CoRB informational messages

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-corb

I see below messages when a CoRB job is submitted to update permissions on a restored database.

```
Jan 06, 2021 1:29:59 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.QueryUrisLoader logQueueStatus
INFO: queued 100,000/112,551,188 : /Position/4638075/1.xml
....
Jan 06, 2021 1:49:52 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager submitUriTasks
INFO: received 76,150,000/112,551,188: /Position/4638075/1.xml
...
Jan 06, 2021 2:49:58 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Monitor showProgress
INFO: completed 19868000/112551188, 4,319 tps(avg), 0 tps(cur), ETC 17:57:27, 96 active threads.
```

As per my understanding, CoRB first fetches the URIs and then updates the docs. 'Info: completed' shows the docs updated so far, what does 'Info: queued' and 'Info: received' mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `INFO: queued` message [is logged every 25,000 URIs processed](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/blob/master/src/main/java/com/marklogic/developer/corb/QueryUrisLoader.java#L233) as they are being enqueued, in order to provide feedback with a status update as they are read from the *URIS-MODULE* resultSequence.

The `INFO: received` message [is logged every 50,000 URIs processed](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/blob/master/src/main/java/com/marklogic/developer/corb/Manager.java#L917) as they are being dequeued, in order to provide feedback with a status update as they are being processed from the queue.

Comment: Mads, my understanding is that the URIs read are stored locally (probably in a queue) and then they are processed with the process module. Does queueing relate to reading the URIs i.e. the rate at which URIs are being stored in the queue? and does dequeue here refer to reading off the queue and sending to ML for processing?

Comment: Yes, reading the URIs and adding to the queue (either in-memory, or spilling over to temp file if DISK-QUEUE is enabled) and then plucking from the queue to send to the process module